# Remove duplicate objects from array by a certain merge algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, merge, higher-order-functions

Here's what I have in mind:

Given an array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Kirk",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Spock",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Kirk",
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

I am trying to get:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Kirk",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Spock",
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

I am wondering if there's already an algorithm, perhaps combining some higher order functions to achieve this. **I could do this easily with loops, but I am looking for a way to solve it using higher order functions**. If someone could point me to what I should use to achieve this, it would be great. Again, **I'm looking for something as elegant as possible** (two maps and a filter would not be a big improvement from loops).

**This is my current solution and I'm looking for something better** (and by better I mean more expressive):

```
function mergeDuplicates(input) {
  var output = [];
  var existingItem = null;
  input.forEach(function (inputItem) {
    existingItem = _.find(output, function (outputItem) {
      return inputItem.name === outputItem.name;
    });
    existingItem ? existingItem.count += 1 : output.push({
      name: inputItem.name,
      count: 1
    });
    existingItem = null;
  });
  return output;
}
```

To make line #10 more clear: in the original array, `count` might be either non-existing or 1, hence I set it to 1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have seen this question on StackOverflow before. (Don't know what the answer is myself)

Comment: if you don't mind external lib. Try underscore.js uniq function. http://underscorejs.org/#uniq

Comment: @David, doesn't matter since I doubt the answer meets my criteria anyway.

Comment: what if the original array contains an object with `"count"` greater than `1`?

Comment: @groovy It won't. In fact, it is without `count` initially.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way would be to hash each object if it does not already exist, and delete the ones that you found already hashed in your structure. This way, you'd be checking the existence of each object only 1 (depends on your hash scheme).

Answer (score 2):

Just a function if you would like to use.

```
function merge(arr) {    
   for(var o = {}, i; i=arr.shift(); o[i.name] = i.count + (o[i.name] || 0));
   for(i in o) arr.push({name:i, count:o[i]});
}
```

Calling :

```
var myArray = [{"name":"Kirk","count":1},
               {"name":"Spock","count":1},
               {"name":"Kirk","count":1}];

merge(myArray);   

// myArray is now :  [{"name":"Kirk","count":2}, {"name":"Spock","count":1}]
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for, but an interesting solution.

Comment: Very neat trick, won't work for an object with more than 2 properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) which is actually a fold.

```
a.reduce(function(p, c) {
        var n = c.name;
        if (p[n])
            p[n].count++;
        else
            p[n] = c;
        return p;
    }, {})
```

will give you a object with "Kirk" and "Spock" as the key, what you want as values.

Comment: I actually want the output to be like in my example -- with `name` and `count` as the keys

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I couldn't resist trying to solve it.  Instead of two maps and a filter, we use a sort and then a reduce.  This was a fun one to sort out :-)

```
function mergeDuplicates(list, prop, cb){
  return list.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a[prop] < b[prop]){ return -1;}
    if(a[prop] > b[prop]){return 1;}
    return 0;
  }).reduce(function(acc, item, index, array){
    if(index > 0 && array[index-1][prop] === item[prop]){
      cb(acc[acc.length-1], item);
      return acc;
    }else{
      var newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
      cb(newItem);
      acc.push(newItem);
      return acc;
    }
  }, []);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var newList = mergeDuplicates(list, "name", function(item, dup){
    if(dup){
      item.count++;
    }else{
      item.count = 1;
    }        
});
```

EDIT: Here's another take at it using reduce and using an object as a hashmap to store duplicates (similar to some of the other answers).  This one uses [ramdajs](http://ramdajs.com/)

```
const mergeDups = (cb, prop, list) => R.pipe(
  R.reduce((acc, item) => (
    R.has(item[prop], acc) ?
      R.assoc(item[prop], cb(acc[item[prop]], item), acc) :
      R.assoc(item[prop], cb(item), acc)     
  ), {}), 
  R.values
)(list);

const cb = (i, d) => ( !R.isNil(d) ? 
  R.assoc('count', i.count + 1, i) :
  R.assoc('count', 1, i) )

mergeDups(cb, 'name', items);
```

[Here it is in the repl on Ramda's site](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?var%20items%20%3D%0A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Kirk%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22count%22%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Spock%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22count%22%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Kirk%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22count%22%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aconst%20mergeDups%20%3D%20%28cb%2C%20prop%2C%20list%29%20%3D%3E%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20R.reduce%28%28acc%2C%20item%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.has%28item%5Bprop%5D%2C%20acc%29%20%3F%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20R.assoc%28item%5Bprop%5D%2C%20cb%28acc%5Bitem%5Bprop%5D%5D%2C%20item%29%2C%20acc%29%20%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20R.assoc%28item%5Bprop%5D%2C%20cb%28item%29%2C%20acc%29%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%29%2C%20%7B%7D%29%2C%20%0A%20%20R.values%0A%29%28list%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20cb%20%3D%20%28i%2C%20d%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%20%21R.isNil%28d%29%20%3F%20%0A%20%20R.assoc%28%27count%27%2C%20i.count%20%2B%201%2C%20i%29%20%3A%0A%20%20R.assoc%28%27count%27%2C%201%2C%20i%29%20%29%0A%0AmergeDups%28cb%2C%20%27name%27%2C%20items%29%3B)

Answer (score 0):

Try this better i'll useful resolve your issues

```js
cleanup(arrayOfObj, 'name');

function cleanup(arr, prop) {
  var new_arr = [];
  var lookup = {};
  for (var i in arr) {
   lookup[arr[i][prop]] = arr[i];
  }
  for (i in lookup) {
   new_arr.push(lookup[i]); 
  }
  return new_arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another version using [`reduce function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var items =
[
    {
        "name": "Kirk",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Spock",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Kirk",
        "count": 1
    }
];
    

var filtered = items.reduce(function(prev, current,index){ 
    if(!(current.name in prev.keys)) {
       prev.keys[current.name] = index;
       prev.result.push(current);
   } 
   else{
       prev.result[prev.keys[current.name]].count += current.count; 
   }
   return prev;
},{result: [], keys: []}).result;

    

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filtered,null,2);
```

```html
<pre id='output' />
```